# Generate database or backup from DbContext file in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a problem. I lost my database in PostgreSQL and I only have a `DbContext` file that I generated it from my lost database.

If you have an idea about how to get a backup or database from my `dbContext` file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like someone will take backups in future.....

Answer (score 0):

The EF Core will generate the database according to the DBContext's model. It will just create the new table without any data inside it.  That means it couldn't backup or restore your data.

I suggest you could check the PostgreSQL's backups to see if it auto create the backup database and remember backup the database in the future.

Comment: Can i just get the tables and the relations between them without getting my data

Comment: Sure you could . You could use migrate action follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#create-your-first-migration) to know the table column and the relationship.